# Python 3.5 pip 9 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bytes'

Tags: python, pip, python-3.5

What is the problem? I tried "**python -m pip install -U pip**" and "**python -m pip install --upgrade pip**" both with the same error (and "**pip install -U  --force-reinstall pip**"). what should I do?

```
C:\Users\Peyman\PycharmProjects\untitled3>python -m pip install -U pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 9.0.3
    Uninstalling pip-9.0.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-9.0.3
  Rolling back uninstall of pip
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Peyman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Peyman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\Users\Peyman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Users\Peyman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "C:\Users\Peyman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "C:\Users\Peyman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 462, in move_wheel_files
    generated.extend(maker.make(spec))
  File "C:\Users\Peyman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 372, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\Peyman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 276, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "C:\Users\Peyman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 212, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
  File "C:\Users\Peyman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 351, in _get_launcher
    result = finder(distlib_package).find(name).bytes
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bytes'
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try using `easy_install -U pip`, according to this [bug report](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2344).

Edit: Okay, go to "https://pypi.org/simple/pip/", and download the latest .whl file (scroll to the bottom). When you have it, open cmd in the same folder (by clicking File -> open powershell/cmd in the file explorer), and type

`pip install filename`, with filename being the name of the file you downloaded (Should be `pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`).

Try that and tell me if it works.

Comment: I can run "python -m easy_install -U pip" and successfully upgrade pip. I found after the installation, pip.exe is upgraded (pip -V shows the new version), but "python -m pip -V" still shows the old version. Anyway it works for me!

Comment: first tried downloading the `*whl` file but it didn't work, but then the `easy_install`method worked

Comment: That happily solves the problem for pip version 19.2.1 to 19.2.3 (python 3.7.4).

Answer (score 22):

You can try this following:

```
python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
```

Comment: simple great solution

Answer (score 7):

My answer is a variation of assmmahmud's but for me I had to use the option --user.
I'm on windows so from CMD.exe;

```
py -m pip install --user --force-reinstall -U
```

If I don't use the --user option then the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Download `get-pip.py` from [the official site](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/)  and run this code:

```
$ python get-pip.py
```

or on Windows, this one:

```
py get-pip.py
```