# How to suppress outdated pip warning

Tags: python, windows, pip

Every `pip` command ends with a warning:

> You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade
>   pip' command.

However, updating pip doesn't work, see below. Can I suppress the warning, and how? Can I update pip, and how?

[image]

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install --upgrade pip Collecting pip
>   Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/b6/9cfa56b4081ad13874b0c6f96af8ce16cfbc1cb06bedf8e9164ce5551ec1/pip-19.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   (1.4MB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 7.3MB/s Installing collected packages: pip   Found existing installation: pip 18.1
>       Uninstalling pip-18.1:
>         Successfully uninstalled pip-18.1   Rolling back uninstall of pip Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Dzenan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\base_command.py",
>   line 143, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "C:\Users\Dzenan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip_internal\commands\install.py",
>   line 366, in run
>       use_user_site=options.use_user_site,   File "C:\Users\Dzenan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip_internal\req__init__.py",
>   line 49, in install_given_reqs
>       **kwargs   File "C:\Users\Dzenan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip_internal\req\req_install.py",
>   line 760, in install
>       use_user_site=use_user_site, pycompile=pycompile,   File "C:\Users\Dzenan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip_internal\req\req_install.py",
>   line 382, in move_wheel_files
>       warn_script_location=warn_script_location,   File "C:\Users\Dzenan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip_internal\wheel.py",
>   line 441, in move_wheel_files
>       generated.extend(maker.make(spec))   File "C:\Users\Dzenan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip_vendor\distlib\scripts.py",
>   line 403, in make
>       self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)   File "C:\Users\Dzenan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip_vendor\distlib\scripts.py",
>   line 307, in _make_script
>       self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)   File
>   "C:\Users\Dzenan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip_vendor\distlib\scripts.py",
>   line 243, in _write_script
>       launcher = self._get_launcher('t')   File "C:\Users\Dzenan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip_vendor\distlib\scripts.py",
>   line 382, in _get_launcher
>       result = finder(distlib_package).find(name).bytes AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bytes' You are using pip version
>   18.1, however version 19.3.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip --version pip 18.1 from
>   C:\Users\Dzenan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip
>   (python 3.7)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.5 pip 9 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bytes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52460484/python-3-5-pip-9-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-bytes)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError%3A+%27NoneType%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27bytes%27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upgrade pip on Windows, you may find answers in [this thread](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5820). This seems to be the solution:

```
python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
```

Or to answer your actual question about suppressing pip warnings, pip has the `-q/-qq/-qqq` option to suppress logging output.

Comment: I needed the --user flag too: `python -m pip install --user --force-reinstall -U pip`.