# Getting Error in upgrading pip AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bytes'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycharm

I tried upgrading pip using:

```
(venv) C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\PycharmProjects\untitled>pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/b6/9cfa56b4081ad13874b0c6f96af8ce16cfbc1cb06bedf8e9164ce5551ec1/pip-19.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.0.3
    Uninstalling pip-19.0.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-19.0.3
  Rolling back uninstall of pip
  Moving to c:\users\divyanshu gupta\pycharmprojects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg
   from C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Lib\site-packages\~ip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg
  Moving to c:\users\divyanshu gupta\pycharmprojects\untitled\venv\scripts\pip-script.py
   from C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-y1i2neb1\pip-script.py
  Moving to c:\users\divyanshu gupta\pycharmprojects\untitled\venv\scripts\pip.exe
   from C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-y1i2neb1\pip.exe
  Moving to c:\users\divyanshu gupta\pycharmprojects\untitled\venv\scripts\pip.exe.manifest
   from C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-y1i2neb1\pip.exe.manifest
  Moving to c:\users\divyanshu gupta\pycharmprojects\untitled\venv\scripts\pip3-script.py
   from C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-y1i2neb1\pip3-script.py
  Moving to c:\users\divyanshu gupta\pycharmprojects\untitled\venv\scripts\pip3.8-script.py
   from C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-y1i2neb1\pip3.8-script.py
  Moving to c:\users\divyanshu gupta\pycharmprojects\untitled\venv\scripts\pip3.8.exe
   from C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-y1i2neb1\pip3.8.exe
  Moving to c:\users\divyanshu gupta\pycharmprojects\untitled\venv\scripts\pip3.8.exe.manifest
   from C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-y1i2neb1\pip3.8.exe.manifest
  Moving to c:\users\divyanshu gupta\pycharmprojects\untitled\venv\scripts\pip3.exe
   from C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-y1i2neb1\pip3.exe
  Moving to c:\users\divyanshu gupta\pycharmprojects\untitled\venv\scripts\pip3.exe.manifest
   from C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-y1i2neb1\pip3.exe.manifest
```

I am getting following Error.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 179, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 384, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
  File "C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 53, in install_given_reqs
    requirement.install(
  File "C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 910, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(
  File "C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 437, in move_wheel_files
    move_wheel_files(
  File "C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\wheel.py", line 544, in move_wheel_files
    generated.extend(maker.make(spec))
  File "C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 405, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 309, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 245, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
  File "C:\Users\Divyanshu Gupta\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 384, in _get_launcher
    result = finder(distlib_package).find(name).bytes
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bytes'
```

I installed python and pycharm today only and It's the very first thing I was trying to do in python. pip install is neither updating nor I am able to install any other package such as 'pygame' using pip install command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3.5 pip 9 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bytes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52460484/python-3-5-pip-9-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-bytes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have a different pip version already installed and this is what is probably causing the problem.
 You should try to find where it is installed and remove anything pip related.
Try  to type `pip -V` to check the version and the path on cmd. 
Inside the python folder, try removing the other version of pip. If the situation persists update pip using easy_install. e.g. `easy_install -U pip`

For errors with a similar traceback check: [this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7069#issuecomment-544145785)